# aws:userid for the IAM principal used by a Gitlab runner

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, sam

I am trying to set up multi-account AWS SAM deployments with GitLab CI/CD by following this article ([multi-account AWS SAM deployments with GitLab CI/CD](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/02/04/multi-account-aws-sam-deployments-with-gitlab-ci/).

While setting up, in step 2, it asked for The aws:userid for the IAM principal used by the Gitlab runner.

I have gitlab runner on AWS EC2 instance and it doesn't have any IAM role attached to it. And, the runner is working perfectly fine.

Problem is, I can't get the idea of this aws:userid that I need to paste to follow the article.
What exactly i need to input here as the value of "CIAccountSTSCondition"?

I tried to get the idea from AWS documentation but its not helping.